# How to import WordPress site to new WordPress site?

Tags: plugins, migration

I understand the question is too broad. I will explain. I have a WordPress site's assets and I want to import it to a new WordPress account/site. How can I achieve this?

I understand I can use All-In-One WP Migration, but I do not have the `.wpress` file or an `.xml` file. I only have the bare WordPress assets and files.

Comment: Do you also have the database from the original site?

Comment: @QStudio I believe I do. I have a folder called, "mwp_db".

Comment: Perhaps you should confirm that, it'll be an important part of any migration.

Comment: @QStudio I’m new to WordPress. I’m more of a ReactJS developer. What is the DB file called?

Comment: well, if it's an export it might be called something like wp_export.sql - and it also might be compressed, so have .gz or some other zip extension

Comment: @QStudio yes thank you. I have the SQL file.

Comment: Ok - so, you have files and database - so where are you trying to import this to - local or another server?

Comment: @QStudio I want to import it to a new WordPress account.

Comment: Do you mean wordpress.com account? Please try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @QStudio yes I do

Comment: WordPress.com is not self-hosted.. so I doubt you have a copy of the database from there.. so I guess you mean to copy a site on your host to a new install.. can you please take some time to update your question and add as much of this new and further details as possible.

Comment: @QStudio That's exactly what I am trying to do... I already have a copy of the site and I just want to import it onto WP.

Comment: @QStudio I only have the assets like stated in the questions description.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not state any details about the environment of if you are adding to a remote host or localhost - I'll write the steps required to clone an install on a local environment on Windows using XAMPP from a zip of the database and wp-content files - the process is similar in both cases, but each host has their own set-up and panel, so some steps would be different.

1. Create a new database user inside phpmyadmin - check the options to create a database with the same name and grant all access options to this new database - store the details you enter as you'll require these for the wp-config.php file to grant WP access to this database.
2. Go to your new database and select the import tab - find your local .sql file and select this and run the import option - check phpmyadmin for any errors and try to address them.
3. Download the latest version of [WordPress](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/download/) - unzip to the location on your local htdocs that you want this install to be.
4. Edit your hosts and http-vhosts.conf files to set-up and local aliases pointing to your new install location.
5. Copy the entire wp-content folder from your old install to the same location in the new install - overwrite everything as it is all generic
6. Edit the wp-config.php in your new install to include the DB connection details you stored earlier
7. This step is a little tricky, but the site_url and home_url values have probably changed, so you will need to edit these directly in the wp_options table of the new database - these are usually on the first and second page of rows - you can click and edit the value in place with modern version of phpmyadmin
8. Open the wordpress admin in your browser - based on what you added to your vhost and wp_options table - if you remember your user credentials, login and check if it all works...

Comment: step 7: some times there are other tables that contains the url of the site and they should be changed too.

Comment: That might be true - but in a standard single site WP install, those are the only 2 values that need changing - you can do a site-wide search using phpmyadmin to find other matches to the old URL string.